# Deadlock detection algorithm (pseudocode)

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, deadlock

I'm reading Operating System Concepts by Silberschatz G. Gagne, and on the chapter on deadlocks, there is a pseudocode given for deadlock detection as follows:

> 1. Let Work and Finish be vectors of length m and n, respectively. (There are n processes and m resources.)
>
>    Initialize Work = Available. For i = 0, 1, ..., n-1, if Allocation[i]
>      != 0, then Finish[i] = false; **otherwise, Finish[i] = true.**
> 2. Find index i such that both Finish[i] == false && Request[i] <= Work.
>
>    If no such i exists, go to step 4.
> 3. Work = Work + Allocation[i]
>
>    Finish[i] = true;
>
>    Go to step 2.
> 4. If Finish[i] == false for some i, then system is deadlocked. Moreover, if Finish[i] == false, then process Pi is deadlocked.

This is very similar to the Banker's Algorithm. However, there is a slight difference in the bold statement above.

**Can someone explain why does the algorithm immediately sets Finish[i] to be true for process i if the operating system hasn't scheduled any resources to that process. To my knowledge, this definitely doesn't mean it won't be deadlocked, as step 4 mentions (not sure if this correct). Thanks!**

Comment: Your questions is based on `Allocation`, which you didn't define anywhere.

Comment: A process that doesn't need any resources allocated to it can certainly finish (i.e. can't be part of a deadlock).

Answer (score 1):

When this algorithm is run, it detects which processes, if any, are currently involved in a deadlock.

A process that as holding no resources might be waiting on a deadlocked process, but it can't be involved in a deadlock itself, and is irrelevant to the rest of the algorithm (it would have no effect in step 3), so it is ignored by setting `Finish[i]=true`

Note that this algorithm still does not quite identify deadlocked processes correctly.  A process flagged in step 4 may hold resources, and may be blocked waiting on a deadlocked process, but there may be no deadlocked process that will need the resources it holds, and so that process would not be involved in the deadlock itself.